# How to store data on hdfs using flume with existing schema file

Tags: hdfs, avro, flume, flume-ng

I have json data coming from source and i want to dump it on hdfs using flume in avro format for which i already have avsc file, i am using following configuration for sink but thats not picking my avsc file but  creating its own schema :

> agent1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer =
>   org.apache.flume.serialization.AvroEventSerializer$Builder
>   agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = /tmp/data
>   agent1.sinks.sink1.schemaURL=file:///home/tmp/schema.avsc
>   log4j.appender.flume.AvroSchemaUrl=file:///home/tmp/schema.avsc
>   agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 1024
>   agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0 agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType
>   = DataStream agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1

How can i do this?